# How can I add authors in WordPress and assign them a picture?

Tags: wordpress, addition

I know that Wordpress allows us to create a new user and the user's avatar is got from Gravatar service base on their email. How can I add authors in WordPress and assign them a picture (without using Gravatar service)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally haven't yet tried it, but a look (and a try ;) to a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-avatar/) could be appropriate.

Comment: That's the plugin I need. Thank you very much.